# The program I wrote with C++ and socket programming can't clear the message after each message transmission

Tags: c++, sockets, char

The 'line' part in the program needs to be cleared after each message transmission, but I haven't been able to do it somehow.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <iostream>

const char* ip = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 1752;
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")


int main() {

    WSADATA wsadata;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata) != 0) {
        printf("[!] Winsock failed..\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("[!] Socket creat was fail..\n");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(-1);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &(address.sin_addr));

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        printf("[!] Connect was fail.. \n");
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(-1);
    }
    char buffer[1024];

    char name[1024];
    printf("Enter the username: \n");
    std::cin.getline(name, sizeof(name));
    size_t nameCount = strlen(name);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';

    char line[1024];
    printf("Enter the messages: \n");


    while (true) {
        std::cin.getline(line, sizeof(line));
        size_t charCount = strlen(line);
        line[charCount - 1] = '\0';
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s: %s", name, line);
        if (send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("[!] Send failed\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    WSACleanup();
    closesocket(sock);
}
```

I want the 'line' part to be completely cleared after each message transmission and not get mixed up with the next message, but it's not getting cleared properly

Comment: If this is C++ why are you not using just `std::string`, it will handle `'\0'` for you.

Comment: I didn't quite understand. Could you show me with an example?

Comment: Example of what exactly? Instead of using `char line[1024]` and all these C string functions, you can use `std::string`.

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you want to do that. Based on the shown code it appears that it will not make any difference, whatsoever.

Comment: Your current code only uses "C" and does not benefit from anything "C++" has to offer. If this is C++ there are nicer libraries than winsock for socket programming. I prefer using boost::asio. That at least allows you to use more "C++" style coding. That will also allow you to get rid of all the "unsafe" memcpy, printf, strlen, strcspn kind of functions

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting cleared properly"? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: @Eljay the code doesn't need to disable Nagle. It shouldn't be disabled unless the performance benefits are thoroughly measures and warranted.  Most TCP apps won't benefit from that.

Comment: *I want the 'line' part to be completely cleared after each message transmission and not get mixed up with the next message, but it's not getting cleared properly* After each message transmission, `std::memset(line, 0, sizeof line);` to clear out the `line`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not zeroing out the contents of `line` after each `send()`. That is why you are seeing `line` potentially still holding earlier data after the next `cin.getline()`. You can use `std::memset()` for that zeroing, eg:

```
while (std::cin.getline(line, sizeof(line))) {
    ...
    std::memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));
}
```

Another option is to pay attention to how many characters `cin.getline()` actually returns to you, and simply don't use more characters than that.  Then you don't need to waste time zeroing out `line`, or waste time using `strlen()` to figure out the output length. The output length is reported by `cin.gcount()` after `cin.getline()` returns.

Aside from that, I see some other problems with your code:

- a lack of adequate error checking on `cin.getline()` and `send()`.

  - You are not making sure that `cin.getline()` is actually returning usable data to you.
  - `send()` can (and usually does) return fewer bytes than requested, so you need to call it in a loop until all of the bytes have actually been accepted.
- you are sending the `buffer` as-is with no length or terminator to let the receiver know how large the `buffer` content actually is.  You need to either:

  - send the message's length before sending the message itself. Then the receiver can read the length first, then read however many bytes/characters the length says.
  - send a unique terminator after the message, such as `\n` or `\0`. The receiver can then read until that terminator arrives.
- during app shutdown after the `send()` loop, you are calling `WSACleanup()` before `closesocket()`. You need to swap them around.

That being said, there is really no good reason to use `char[]` arrays in this simple code.  You should use `std::string` and `std::getline()` instead.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

const char* ip = "127.0.0.1";
u_short port = 1752;

bool sendAll(SOCKET sock, const void *buffer, size_t bufsize) {
    const char *pbuf = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer);
    while (buflen > 0) {
        int sent = send(sock, pbuf, static_cast<int>(buflen), 0);
        if (sent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "[!] Send failed\n";
            return false;
        }
        pbuf += sent;
        buflen -= sent;
    }
    return true;
}

bool sendStr(SOCKET sock, const std::string& str) {
    return sendAll(sock, str.c_str(), str.size());
}

int main() {

    WSADATA wsadata;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsadata) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "[!] Winsock startup failed..\n";
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cerr << "[!] Socket create failed..\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in address = {};
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &(address.sin_addr));

    if (connect(sock, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&address), sizeof(address)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "[!] Connect failed.. \n";
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter the username:\n";

    if (std::getline(std::cin, name) && !name.empty()) {

        std::string line;
        std::cout << "Enter the messages:\n";

        while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
            if (!sendStr(sock, name + ": " + line + "\n")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```